# I am not getting api message in pusher(Debug Console)

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I'm trying to make one to one chat in laravel app using Pusher
but i am not getting the API Message from my app to pusher Debug Console.

Its shows every other thing accept this,
When a session is created between users then it will create a session id in session database and that should show in api message..

My codes :-
SessionEvent

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SessionEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $session;
    public $session_by;

    public function __construct($session, $session_by)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->session_by = $session_by;
        //$this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    }
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('Chat');
    }
}
```

SessionController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Session;
use App\Http\Resources\SessionResource;
use App\Events\SessionEvent;

class SessionController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $session = Session::create(['user1_id' => auth()->id(), 'user2_id' => $request->friend_id]);
        $modifiedSession = new SessionResource($session);
        broadcast(new SessionEvent($modifiedSession, auth()->id()));
        return $modifiedSession;
    }
}
```

Please Let me know where is my mistake...

Thank You

Comment: This is naive but did you set the correct parameters in `.env`? And did you check your log file?

Comment: Yeah,they are correct..Pusher is not only receiving api message in Debug Console